# VueJS - disable space in input text

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component called `TextInput.vue`, and inside I created a div.

```
<div ts-text-input :ts-text-input-filled="setFilledAttribute && !!value"
:ts-text-input-not-valid="!valueValid">

<input :value="value" @input="setValue" @keyup.enter="enterClicked" :placeholder="placeholder" :title="title">
```

what I wanted to do now is that to disable some spaces inside the input box so that the user is unable to type in with spaces/spacebar (like, e.g., username input box)

Here is what I have done; I try to use the function `trim()`, but it seems I can't still fix it.

in the computed function

```
    computed: {
  value: function() {
    const {valueGetter, valueGetterOptions} = this,
      getter = this.$store.getters[valueGetter];
      value.trim();
    return valueGetterOptions ? getter(valueGetterOptions) : getter;
  },
```

Any hints would be helpful. thanks. (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: For Headless UI (Tailwind CSS Labs), this may be relevant: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/discussions/820 (use `stopPropagation` to prevent keystrokes from bubbling up).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can directly prevent that the user adds a white space to your input field. `preventDefault()` tells the user agent that the default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

```
<input @keydown.space="(event) => event.preventDefault()">
```

Or to make it even shorter (as [Sovalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521679/vuejs-disable-space-in-input-text/53521999#comment93912770_53521999) pointed out):

```
<input @keydown.space.prevent>
```

Comment: you also can write like this: `<input @keydown.space.prevent>`. Your answer is very clever btw

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: oh yea! i knew it can be done something very simple like this! but i really had no idea. I tried both of the code, both are actually do the job. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Does not prevent from pasting text with spaces.

Comment: when we tried spam space its input dot on input , did u know why ?

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo soft keyboards on mobile phones and tablets usually have a setting to convert double space to a period and space. You can disable the setting if it annoys you.

Answer (score 4):

To prevent spaces on all input events - keypress, paste or drag and drop text:

```
const removeEventSpaces = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const left    = e.target.value.substring(0, e.target.selectionStart);
  const right   = e.target.value.substring(e.target.selectionEnd, e.target.value.length);
  const pasted  = (e.dataTransfer || e.clipboardData).getData('text').replace(/ /g, '');
  e.target.value = left + pasted + right;
}

<input @keydown.space.prevent @paste="removeEventSpaces" @drop="removeEventSpaces"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

@keydown.native.space didn't work for me. @keydown.native.space.prevent did.

Comment: this will be because you're using it on a custom component, but it's a good point for those that are confused as to why this isn't working

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```
value.replace(/\s/, '')
```

or to be sure the data is stored without any capital letters

```
value.replace(/\s/, '').toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

u could use get and set

```
var inputData = ''

export default {
    name: 'yourFromComponent',
    computed: {
        inputValue: {
            get () {
                return inputData
            },
            set (value) {
                inputData = value.replace(/\s/g,'')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you use vuex just change the inputData to your store referenz