# How to disable only leading space in the input text field Vue JS

Tags: forms, vue.js

I have an input address field with a custom form validation. I would like to disable only the leading space when user starts typing some text

[image: Vue JS Form]

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521679/vuejs-disable-space-in-input-text/53521999#53521999) post however, this approach disables white space completely

I have also tried using `.trim()` method along with `.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, "")`  still didn't work

Here is how it looks when I have leading whitespace.

***Having leading whitespace doesn't let form validation error message to be displayed***

**Please Note my component is a child component and I am looking for a solution which can be implemented within my component.**

[image]

Need some help

Tried this approach but it disables all spaces by default

```
<input 
  v-on:keydown='key'
  class="input search-city"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Street address or zip code"
  v-model="search_string"                         
/>

<script>
 methods: {
   key: function(event){
      if(event.keyCode === 32){
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to disable white space in the input, or just trim the white space from the generated v-model value?

Comment: need to disable in the input so that user's first input can be a character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the `.trim()` method and `.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, "")` will remove leading and trailing space from your string.

To remove just the leading white-space use `.replace(/^\s*/, "")`

RegEx Explanation:

- `^\s*`  is any repeated (*) white space (\s) following the start (^) of the input.
- `\s*$`  is any repeated (*) white space (\s) preceeding the end ($) of the input.
- `(^\s*)|(\s*$)` is either of the above (`|` = OR)
- the `/g` option is "global", so it will replace multiple occurrences of the same match (not required in this case, since we are already using `\s*` to match repeated consecutive whitespace characters)
- the `/i` option means case-insensitive match, which is not required in this case.

Alternatively, try:

```
<input v-model="search_string" @keydown.space="preventLeadingSpace"/>
```

```
  methods: {
    preventLeadingSpace(e) {
      // only prevent the keypress if the value is blank
      if (!e.target.value) e.preventDefault();
      // otherwise, if the leading character is a space, remove all leading white-space
      else if (e.target.value[0]==' ') e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/^\s*/, "");
    },
  }
```

Comment: an alternative way didn't work. Error: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
My initial method also had the same error

Comment: Can you show your exact code - I don't understand how `e.target` can be null in this case.  Anyway, you could try `else if (e.target.value && e.target.value[0]==' ')...`

Comment: In your component definition, are you initlizing `search_string` as `null` or `""`?  If `null` try changing the initial value to `""`.

Comment: I am about to try it tomorrow and will let you know... yes it was set to 'null'

Comment: it worked as I changed search_string from null to  ""

Comment: Alternative worked like charm

Answer (score 3):

> need to disable in the input so that user's first input can be a
> character.

You can use [custom directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).

Put this code in the file where you initiate vue

```
Vue.directive('disable-leading-space', { // you can rename it to your liking
    update (el) {
        // using regex to only remove spaces at the beginning
        el.value = el.value.replace(/^\s+/g, ""); // or you can use your own preferred way to remove leading spaces
        el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
    }
})
```

and then you can use the directive like this

```
<input v-disable-leading-space v-model="myText">
```

Using directive like this makes the code to be reusable in all your vue components.

Comment: since I have a component I can't use Vue.directive directly ...

Comment: @DurdonaAbdusamikovna I mean put it in where you initiate vue, not in component. The file in where you `import Vue from 'vue'` and initiate `new Vue({ router, store, render: h => h(App) }).$mount('#app')`. Put it after import and before new Vue

Comment: I can't put it there since my component is a child component ... need a solution within my component

Comment: @DurdonaAbdusamikovna No problem, the directives you register will be available globally anyway. Or maybe I misunderstand your structure, put your child component, and how you call it in the question.

Comment: just edited my question. Thanks for your efforts anyway

Answer (score 1):

Another much simpler solution:

```
<input v-model.trim="search_string" .....
```