# Remove white space from v-text-field Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `v-text-field` in vue, and I will like to remove all white spaces or prevent any white space from it. For instance `'Project Number'` input should be `'ProjectNumber'`.

I have a function but this doesn't work, I tried keyup too.

```
<v-text-field
  @input='removeWhiteSpace(row.newCol)'
  outlined
  dense
  color="primary"
  style="width: 200px;"
  v-model="row.newCol">
</v-text-field>

removeWhiteSpace(text) {
  return text.replace(/[\s\/]/g, '');
}
```

Answer (score 9):

There is a native vue modifier for that, `v-model.trim`

```
<v-text-field
  outlined
  dense
  color="primary"
  style="width: 200px;"
  v-model.trim="row.model">
</v-text-field>
```

Comment: I think trim only removes the ending white space, i rephrased the question

Comment: v-model.trim removes whitespace from both the end of the text

Comment: Yes, I am trying to prevent input of any white space

Comment: This works great when you are copy pasting the value. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
<v-text-field
  @keydown.space.prevent
  outlined
  dense
  color="primary"
  style="width: 200px;"
  v-model="row.newCol">
</v-text-field>
```

From here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53521999/10642485

Comment: Yes I found this on a forum. This is what I ended up using.

Comment: This one worked for me

Comment: trimming is cut off the trailing space, not disallow the space at all

Answer (score 1):

For this, I'd recommend skipping `v-model` and just directly assign the transformed value

```html
<v-text-field
  :value="row.newCol"
  @input="row.newCol = removeWhiteSpace($event)"
  outlined
  dense
  color="primary"
  style="width: 200px;">
</v-text-field>
```